# how would i get the coordidnates of the red pixels and the white block pixels on this circle?

Tags: python, image, pixel

[image]

If I have the above image how would i go about finding the pixels in the white section of the circle (the block) and the red section on the circle?

any help appreciated, im new to python

Comment: Just load it into Photoshop or GIMP and measure it.

Comment: oh, thats not an option because in the next screenshot - the positions of both would change